# imprimir arreglos anidados en objetos json con query

Tags: javascript, jquery

hola tengo este problema para imprimir este json

```
{
"delegacion":"\u00c1lvaro Obreg\u00f3n",
"estado":"Ciudad de M\u00e9xico",
"region":"Centro",
"colonias":[
{"idcp":"27886","asentamiento":"Ampliaci\u00f3n El Capul\u00edn"},
{"idcp":"27887","asentamiento":"Liberales de 1857"},
{"idcp":"27888","asentamiento":"Bel\u00e9m de las Flores"},
{"idcp":"27889","asentamiento":"El Capul\u00edn"}
]
}
```

ya logre imprimir los primeros

```
"delegacion":"\u00c1lvaro Obreg\u00f3n",
"estado":"Ciudad de M\u00e9xico",
"region":"Centro",

console.log(data.idcp);
```

pero cuando quiero acceder a los otros para meterlos en un select me marca error y se queda cargando la pagina

este obkjeto es el que quiero meter dentro de un select

```
"colonias":[
{"idcp":"27886","asentamiento":"Ampliaci\u00f3n El Capul\u00edn"},
{"idcp":"27887","asentamiento":"Liberales de 1857"},
{"idcp":"27888","asentamiento":"Bel\u00e9m de las Flores"},
{"idcp":"27889","asentamiento":"El Capul\u00edn"}
]
```

ayuda por fa

Comment: Bueno, dinos cual es tu error, muéstranos el código en donde estás intentando añadir esos valores al select

Comment: quiero imprimir este objeto json n{
  "delegacion": "Álvaro Obregón",
  "estado": "Ciudad de México",
  "region": "Centro",
  "colonias": [
    {
      "idcp": "27886",
      "asentamiento": "Ampliación El Capulín"
    },
    {
      "idcp": "27887",
      "asentamiento": "Liberales de 1857"
    },
    {
      "idcp": "27888",
      "asentamiento": "Belém de las Flores"
    },
    {
      "idcp": "27889",
      "asentamiento": "El Capulín"
    }
  ]
}o me marca error , ya borre cookes.

Comment: Ya leí en un comentario que el error quedo solucionado, no ?

Comment: si ya quedo gracias

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debes acceder primero a `data.colonias` y ahí ya puedes acceder directamente a `idcp` y `asentamiento`

Intenta con esto:

```
var data = {
        "delegacion":"\u00c1lvaro Obreg\u00f3n",
        "estado":"Ciudad de M\u00e9xico",
        "region":"Centro",
        "colonias":[
            {"idcp":"27886","asentamiento":"Ampliaci\u00f3n El Capul\u00edn"},
            {"idcp":"27887","asentamiento":"Liberales de 1857"},
            {"idcp":"27888","asentamiento":"Bel\u00e9m de las Flores"},
            {"idcp":"27889","asentamiento":"El Capul\u00edn"}
        ]
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < data.colonias.length; i++) {
        console.log('idcp: '+data.colonias[i].idcp + ' asentamiento: '+data.colonias[i].asentamiento);
    }
```

Comment: gracias ya quedo  y entendí todo muy claro se lo agradezco

Answer (score 1):

Intenta con:

```
let col = data.colonias

col.map((colonia) => { console.log(colonia) })
```